# Creating a custom shape with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a customised shape with CSS but I can't quite create what I want to achieve. The shape will be representing the selected item on the main navigation which is shown here:

As you can see I have styled the element `<a class="selected">` with the CSS property `border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;` that displays a shape that has a similar appearance to a pill.

However what i am trying to achieve is a shape that has straight top and bottom edges but has rounded left and right sides as shown in the image below: Are there any CSS properties I can apply to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: IF you would manage to make this in CSS, I will salute you. However, I'm positive it would require CSS3, so IE8 and lower will be pissed about this. I would just use images.

Comment: Looks like a circle and the containing div has its overflow set to hidden.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the following css:

```
div{
    border-radius: 10px / 100%;
}
```

This hardly known slash notation enables you to use elliptical border radii as you can see in the images of the [MDN border-radius Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius).

With the slash notation you can define the vertical and horizontal border-radius like this:

```
border-radius: [up to 4 horizontal values] / [up to four vertical values];
```

This means you can define ellipses with different radii for each corner separately (following the normal rules of defining multiple values):

```
    /*           horizontal values | vertical values   */
    /*              ↓ top-left     |  ↓ top-left       */
    border-radius: 5px 6px 7px 8px / 10px 11px 12px 13px;
    /*             bottom-right ↑  |    bottom-right ↑ */
```

If you distort the ellipse strongly enough, you can achieve the effect needed for your case.

```css
div{
    background:#bada55;
    color:white;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px; 
    border-radius: 10px / 90%;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #792;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(70,90,10,.3);
}
```

```html
<div>sponsorship</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx6jP/)

Comment: Can I ask what the slash notation with the second value is defining?

I understand that the first value is defining the circle radius but what is the / and 100% doing?

Comment: `border-radius: (horizontal radius values) / [radius for all corners];  `

Comment: @user1554264 you can imagine border-radius to have two possible radii for each corner. The images in [MDN border radius docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/border-radius) explain this pretty well. You can define up to eight values, for each corner a horizontal and a vertical border radius.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in css3.  This link contains various shapes that you can use http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/.  I think that you would want to use something similar to "TV Screen"

```
#tv {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50% / 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
#tv:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a link in your answer.

Comment: May I ask you to include the link you have mentioned?